# Renaming JPG images in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and image analysis. I would really appreciate some insight/help into the following problem. I am trying to rename images (jpg) in a folder that have a random name into specific (new) names. I made the an excel file with two columns the first column contains the old names and the second column the new names. I found the next code on stack overflow ([Rename image file name in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004211/rename-image-file-name-in-matlab)):

```
dirData = dir('*.jpg');         %# Get the selected file data
fileNames = {dirData.name};     %# Create a cell array of file names
for iFile = 1:numel(fileNames)  %# Loop over the file names
  newName = sprintf('image%05d.jpg',iFile);  %# Make the new name
  movefile(fileNames{iFile},newName);        %# Rename the file
end
```

The code gives all the photos a new name based on the old one but that is not what I want, the new names I use are not linked to the old ones. I tried the following code :

```
g= xlsread('names.xlsx') % names.xlsx the excel file with old and new names     
for i=1:nrows(g)
image=open(g(i,1));
save(g(i,2),image);
end
```

It doesn't work. I get the error message :using open (line 68)
NAME must contain a single string. I don't think open is the right function to use.

Thank you !

Comment: Why not create a cell array the same size as `fileNames` with the corresponding new names?

Comment: What is `g(i,1)` if not a string? Also why not `movefile(g(i,1), g(i,2))`?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your suggestion. The images are in a random order in the directory and the new names have to be assigned specifically to the right 'old' image. If I use this code it will assign the new filenames to the images in the order they are in the directory. That wouldn't be the right assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
% Get the jpeg names
dir_data  = dir('*.jpg');
jpg_names = {dir_data.name};

% Rename the files according to the .xlsx file
[~,g,~] = xlsread('names.xlsx'); % Thanks to the post of Sean
old_names = g(:,1);
new_names = g(:,2);

for k = 1:numel(old_names)
        % check if the file exists
        ix_file = strcmpi(old_names{k}, jpg_names);
        if any(ix_file)
                movefile(old_names{k}, new_names{k});
        end;
end;
```

Comment: @YV3003 Do have duplicates in the old file column in the excel file? Also, is the first column the column for the old file names?

Comment: Thank you it worked ! The images where located inside a folder inside my MATLAB folder. That is what caused the error.

Comment: @YV3003 Then it would be nice to chose my answer as the correct one. :-)

Comment: a little error on the second line : dir_data instead of dirData

Comment: @YV3003 Sorry for changing the naming conventions that you are used to. Old habits die hard, and camel case is not one of my old habits. :-D I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, you saved me a lot of work. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `g = xlsread(file)` reads only numeric data from `file` (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html)). The third output argument of `xlsread` returns raw data including strings; does the following work? (i don't have excel and can't test it)

```
[~, ~, g] = xlsread('names.xlsx')
for i = 1:nrows(g)
  movefile(g{i,1}, g{i,2})
end
```